Does the product of two reproducing kernels lie within the same RKHS?
Consider $k$ to be the reproducing kernel for the functions defined on the space $X\times Y$. Denote the $\mathcal{H}_{(X,Y)}$ as its RKHS. I would like to approximate a conditional expectation using conditional mean embedding
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{p({x',y'} |x,y)}\left[f(x',y')g({x',y'})\right] &= \left\langle f.g\ , \mu_{X',Y' |x,y}\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_{(X,Y)}}\nonumber\\
& \approx\left\langle \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ik((x'_i,y'_i),\cdot)\sum_{l=1}^n \beta_{l} k((x'_l,y'_l),.)\ ,\ \sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_j(x,y)k(.,(x'_j,y'_j))\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_{(X,Y)}}\nonumber\\
& =  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{l=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_i\beta_{l} \gamma_j(x,y)\left\langle k((x'_i,y'_i),\cdot)k((x'_l,y'_l),\cdot),\ k(\cdot,(x'_j,y'_j))\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_{(X,Y)}}
\end{align}
would the Kernel Product  $k((x'_i,y'_i),\cdot)k((x'_l,y'_l),\cdot)$ lie within $\mathcal{H}_{(X,A)}$? (I guess no, right?) Would it be kernel?
If not, can we approximating it by basis functions in $\mathcal{H}_{(X,Y)}$?
is this correct?
$$\left\langle k((x'_i,y'_i),\cdot)k((x'_l,y'_l),\cdot),\ k(\cdot,(x'_j,y'_j))\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_{(X,Y)}}=k((x'_i,y'_i),(x'_j,y'_j))k((x'_l,y'_l),(x'_j,y'_j))$$
